# insert 3 Tiks as a one picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, input, matlab2tikz

[image]I want to insert this 3 tikz like the picture above
I use Matlab2Tikz and i have a problems with it
I can change every position (at=)
but this hard to do and take a long time
this is the 3 tikz generated by matlab2tikz
I want to use input(name.tex)

```
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% First Tikz %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

            \begin{tikzpicture}

        \begin{axis}[%
        width=6.458in,
        height=2.002in,
        at={(1.083in,3.476in)},
        scale only axis,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=15,
        xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
        xlabel={Longueur [m]},
        ymin=20,
        ymax=60,
        ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
        ylabel={$\text{Température [}^\circ\text{C]}$},
        axis background/.style={fill=white},
        xmajorgrids,
        ymajorgrids,
        legend style={at={(0.731,0.921)}, anchor=south west, legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=white!15!black}
        ]
        \addplot [color=red, line width=2.0pt]
          table[row sep=crcr]{%
        0   60\\
        0.6 58.2422860842627\\
        1.2 56.6097827135196\\
        1.8 55.1008390654262\\
        2.4 53.6983457588748\\
        3   52.4031055642289\\
        3.6 51.1980468733326\\
        4.2 50.0864145734772\\
        4.8 49.0508026074216\\
        5.4 48.0969489200673\\
        6   47.2067330247575\\
        6.6 46.3884947789133\\
        7.2 45.623002700944\\
        7.8 44.9213678568538\\
        8.4 44.2628254074828\\
        9   43.6614912955672\\
        9.6 43.0946093537078\\
        10.2    42.5796038678164\\
        10.8    42.0912231257453\\
        11.4    41.6505800688117\\
        12  41.2293652659884\\
        12.6    40.8528463044577\\
        13.2    40.4890228447549\\
        13.8    40.1678796111365\\
        14.4    39.8530064435973\\
        15  39.5797772593885\\
        };
        \addlegendentry{Fluide chaud}

        \addplot [color=blue, line width=2.0pt]
          table[row sep=crcr]{%
        0   20\\
        0.6 21.1719747209521\\
        1.2 22.2595912274186\\
        1.8 23.2656950493128\\
        2.4 24.1999453099989\\
        3   25.0635558718899\\
        3.6 25.8661605546952\\
        4.2 26.6073449950241\\
        4.8 27.2969658727417\\
        5.4 27.9329466611327\\
        6   28.5256202326883\\
        6.6 29.071175348496\\
        7.2 29.5806854597249\\
        7.8 30.0484917709108\\
        8.4 30.4866898930294\\
        9   30.8876177140669\\
        9.6 31.2646983217632\\
        10.2    31.6080639948758\\
        10.8    31.9328014426398\\
        11.4    32.2265838113194\\
        12  32.5065362120139\\
        12.6    32.7575620167737\\
        13.2    32.9992468597154\\
        13.8    33.2133493639172\\
        14.4    33.4223949531101\\
        15  33.6045493133708\\
        };
        \addlegendentry{Fluide Froid}

        \end{axis}

        \begin{axis}[%
        width=2.789in,
        height=2.002in,
        at={(1.083in,0.667in)},
        scale only axis,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=1,
        xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
        xlabel={Longueur adimensionnelle [-]},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=1,
        ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
        ylabel={Température adimensionnelle [-]},
        axis background/.style={fill=white},
        xmajorgrids,
        ymajorgrids
        ]
        \addplot [color=red, line width=2.0pt, forget plot]
          table[row sep=crcr]{%
        0   -0\\
        0.04    0.0860771176722571\\
        0.08    0.166022541945048\\
        0.12    0.239917115342254\\
        0.16    0.308598702432005\\
        0.2 0.372027990696816\\
        0.24    0.431040994923242\\
        0.28    0.485478809533588\\
        0.32    0.536193827641397\\
        0.36    0.582905055989428\\
        0.4 0.626499874058642\\
        0.44    0.666569870171705\\
        0.48    0.704056830411705\\
        0.52    0.738416634073142\\
        0.56    0.770666157388152\\
        0.6 0.800114127645579\\
        0.64    0.82787493853683\\
        0.68    0.853095304271001\\
        0.72    0.877011828016837\\
        0.76    0.898590586609769\\
        0.8 0.919217922960301\\
        0.84    0.937656456482359\\
        0.88    0.955473277793484\\
        0.92    0.971200003094069\\
        0.96    0.986619676598071\\
        1   1\\
        };
        \end{axis}

        \begin{axis}[%
        width=8.333in,
        height=6.25in,
        at={(0in,6.25in)},
        scale only axis,
        clip=false,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=1,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=1,
        axis line style={draw=none},
        ticks=none,
        axis x line*=bottom,
        axis y line*=left
        ]
        \node[align=center]
        at (axis cs:0.5,-0.05) {\boldmath$(\dot{m}Cp)_{ch} < (\dot{m}Cp)_{fr}$};
        \end{axis}

        \begin{axis}[%
        width=2.789in,
        height=2.002in,
        at={(4.753in,0.667in)},
        scale only axis,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=1,
        xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
        xlabel={Longueur adimensionnelle [-]},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=1,
        ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
        ylabel={Température adimensionnelle [-]},
        axis background/.style={fill=white},
        xmajorgrids,
        ymajorgrids
        ]
        \addplot [color=blue, line width=2.0pt, forget plot]
          table[row sep=crcr]{%
        0   0\\
        0.04    0.0861457953480524\\
        0.08    0.166090855005231\\
        0.12    0.240044339146409\\
        0.16    0.308716239932408\\
        0.2 0.372195782106014\\
        0.24    0.431191097887369\\
        0.28    0.485671729568455\\
        0.32    0.536362190665889\\
        0.36    0.583109846449379\\
        0.4 0.626674212890625\\
        0.44    0.666775145544934\\
        0.48    0.70422659648922\\
        0.52    0.738612616960049\\
        0.56    0.770822292710784\\
        0.6 0.800292421548015\\
        0.64    0.828009665170759\\
        0.68    0.853248698467887\\
        0.72    0.877118467343273\\
        0.76    0.898712888585209\\
        0.8 0.919290740467402\\
        0.84    0.937742348012608\\
        0.88    0.955507349805372\\
        0.92    0.971244916649378\\
        0.96    0.986610775846745\\
        1   1\\
        };
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}% 

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Second Tikz  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[%
    width=6.458in,
    height=2.002in,
    at={(1.083in,3.476in)},
    scale only axis,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=15,
    xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
    xlabel={Longueur [m]},
    ymin=20,
    ymax=60,
    ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
    ylabel={$\text{Température [}^\circ\text{C]}$},
    axis background/.style={fill=white},
    xmajorgrids,
    ymajorgrids,
    legend style={at={(0.731,0.921)}, anchor=south west, legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=white!15!black}
    ]
    \addplot [color=red, line width=2.0pt]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    0   60\\
    0.6 58.7776348332645\\
    1.2 57.6257077366681\\
    1.8 56.5488849048322\\
    2.4 55.533142320904\\
    3   54.5846308646345\\
    3.6 53.6888444560077\\
    4.2 52.8534727394519\\
    4.8 52.0633330247601\\
    5.4 51.3277392203579\\
    6   50.6306266766885\\
    6.6 49.9830450249816\\
    7.2 49.367828223399\\
    7.8 48.797900823873\\
    8.4 48.2547583690078\\
    9   47.753369491308\\
    9.6 47.2736329167244\\
    10.2    46.8327631818274\\
    10.8    46.4087782880983\\
    11.4    46.0213763868627\\
    12  45.6463808042967\\
    12.6    45.3062507013489\\
    13.2    44.9742657188535\\
    13.8    44.6759675374661\\
    14.4    44.381702467235\\
    15  44.1204654697768\\
    };
    \addlegendentry{Fluide chaud}

    \addplot [color=blue, line width=2.0pt]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    0   20\\
    0.6 21.2228559170426\\
    1.2 22.3729085239176\\
    1.8 23.4501552374234\\
    2.4 24.4639532309607\\
    3   25.4128227501518\\
    3.6 26.3066027900671\\
    4.2 27.1422745774569\\
    4.8 27.930353477233\\
    5.4 28.6661962597015\\
    6   29.3612000017676\\
    6.6 30.008985621116\\
    7.2 30.6220513246524\\
    7.8 31.1921430440547\\
    8.4 31.7330971164275\\
    9   32.2346153949974\\
    9.6 32.7121307165636\\
    10.2    33.1530991038253\\
    10.8    33.5748337604652\\
    11.4    33.9623072445142\\
    12  34.3350270270729\\
    12.6    34.6752048895403\\
    13.2    35.0048915196913\\
    13.8    35.3032165027917\\
    14.4    35.5951633170568\\
    15  35.85640755331\\
    };
    \addlegendentry{Fluide Froid}

    \end{axis}

    \begin{axis}[%
    width=2.789in,
    height=2.002in,
    at={(1.083in,0.667in)},
    scale only axis,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=1,
    xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
    xlabel={Longueur adimensionnelle [-]},
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1,
    ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
    ylabel={Température adimensionnelle [-]},
    axis background/.style={fill=white},
    xmajorgrids,
    ymajorgrids
    ]
    \addplot [color=red, line width=2.0pt, forget plot]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    0   -0\\
    0.04    0.0769773927824497\\
    0.08    0.149519008810551\\
    0.12    0.21733099849995\\
    0.16    0.281296512224227\\
    0.2 0.341028203632703\\
    0.24    0.397439580611159\\
    0.28    0.450046394429651\\
    0.32    0.499804761917564\\
    0.36    0.546128147719719\\
    0.4 0.590028209295366\\
    0.44    0.630809105641815\\
    0.48    0.669551853447909\\
    0.52    0.705442540195765\\
    0.56    0.739646468140343\\
    0.6 0.771221000551574\\
    0.64    0.801431997836821\\
    0.68    0.82919538939329\\
    0.72    0.855895472630752\\
    0.76    0.8802917734479\\
    0.8 0.903906797040198\\
    0.84    0.925326197105136\\
    0.88    0.946232665230102\\
    0.92    0.965017736090942\\
    0.96    0.983548825252973\\
    1   1\\
    };
    \end{axis}

    \begin{axis}[%
    width=8.333in,
    height=6.25in,
    at={(0in,6.25in)},
    scale only axis,
    clip=false,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=1,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1,
    axis line style={draw=none},
    ticks=none,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    axis y line*=left
    ]
    \node[align=center]
    at (axis cs:0.5,-0.05) {\boldmath$(\dot{m}Cp)_{ch} \simeq (\dot{m}Cp)_{fr}$};
    \end{axis}

    \begin{axis}[%
    width=2.789in,
    height=2.002in,
    at={(4.753in,0.667in)},
    scale only axis,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=1,
    xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
    xlabel={Longueur adimensionnelle [-]},
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1,
    ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
    ylabel={Température adimensionnelle [-]},
    axis background/.style={fill=white},
    xmajorgrids,
    ymajorgrids
    ]
    \addplot [color=blue, line width=2.0pt, forget plot]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    0   0\\
    0.04    0.0771206159359437\\
    0.08    0.149649819225429\\
    0.12    0.217587446956305\\
    0.16    0.281523618508965\\
    0.2 0.341365011712371\\
    0.24    0.397732132506308\\
    0.28    0.450434598974842\\
    0.32    0.500135572989705\\
    0.36    0.546542224685216\\
    0.4 0.590373321970617\\
    0.44    0.63122656172057\\
    0.48    0.66989015569514\\
    0.52    0.705843552924974\\
    0.56    0.739959355672478\\
    0.6 0.771588101142333\\
    0.64    0.801703076426661\\
    0.68    0.829513183210251\\
    0.72    0.85611029577954\\
    0.76    0.88054669366767\\
    0.8 0.904052634802546\\
    0.84    0.925506287612849\\
    0.88    0.946298300497392\\
    0.92    0.965112460142155\\
    0.96    0.983524374271102\\
    1   1\\
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}% 

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Third Tikz %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[%
    width=6.458in,
    height=2.002in,
    at={(1.083in,3.476in)},
    scale only axis,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=15,
    xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
    xlabel={Longueur [m]},
    ymin=20,
    ymax=60,
    ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
    ylabel={$\text{Température [}^\circ\text{C]}$},
    axis background/.style={fill=white},
    xmajorgrids,
    ymajorgrids,
    legend style={at={(0.731,0.921)}, anchor=south west, legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=white!15!black}
    ]
    \addplot [color=red, line width=2.0pt]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    0   60\\
    0.6 59.3647493077178\\
    1.2 58.7563210104658\\
    1.8 58.1805874622794\\
    2.4 57.6285690083078\\
    3   57.1068219696446\\
    3.6 56.605922919731\\
    4.2 56.1331528874796\\
    4.8 55.6785737145958\\
    5.4 55.2502415177202\\
    6   54.837627516618\\
    6.6 54.4496207252873\\
    7.2 54.075020193811\\
    7.8 53.7236136265699\\
    8.4 53.383439917122\\
    9   53.0652598668396\\
    9.6 52.7562569435763\\
    10.2    52.4682487786268\\
    10.8    52.1874599496269\\
    11.4    51.9268587791624\\
    12  51.6715983033036\\
    12.6    51.4359024249101\\
    13.2    51.2037297207932\\
    13.8    50.9906765955349\\
    14.4    50.7793728047856\\
    15  50.5869173289617\\
    };
    \addlegendentry{Fluide chaud}

    \addplot [color=blue, line width=2.0pt]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    0   20\\
    0.6 21.2712089630829\\
    1.2 22.4856969012925\\
    1.8 23.6377835190348\\
    2.4 24.7393616850351\\
    3   25.7833896912226\\
    3.6 26.7826473499964\\
    4.2 27.7286437679408\\
    4.8 28.6351875739359\\
    5.4 29.4922380179891\\
    6   30.314784269442\\
    6.6 31.091120196573\\
    7.2 31.8375785390289\\
    7.8 32.5406562978381\\
    8.4 33.2182056811558\\
    9   33.8547781174572\\
    9.6 34.4699357357213\\
    10.2    35.0461170423426\\
    10.8    35.6048009187176\\
    11.4    36.1261253522921\\
    12  36.6337111698228\\
    12.6    37.1051861984516\\
    13.2    37.5665589225563\\
    13.8    37.9927133147384\\
    14.4    38.4123141041482\\
    15  38.7972396510423\\
    };
    \addlegendentry{Fluide Froid}

    \end{axis}

    \begin{axis}[%
    width=2.789in,
    height=2.002in,
    at={(1.083in,0.667in)},
    scale only axis,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=1,
    xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
    xlabel={Longueur adimensionnelle [-]},
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1,
    ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
    ylabel={Température adimensionnelle [-]},
    axis background/.style={fill=white},
    xmajorgrids,
    ymajorgrids
    ]
    \addplot [color=red, line width=2.0pt, forget plot]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    0   -0\\
    0.04    0.0674859357431074\\
    0.08    0.132122391037815\\
    0.12    0.193285515627999\\
    0.16    0.251929264255641\\
    0.2 0.307357125339714\\
    0.24    0.360570197764412\\
    0.28    0.410794980524046\\
    0.32    0.459087255092337\\
    0.36    0.504591178923097\\
    0.4 0.548425278284803\\
    0.44    0.589645227677622\\
    0.48    0.629440961399251\\
    0.52    0.666772681466085\\
    0.56    0.702911077498078\\
    0.6 0.736712974432583\\
    0.64    0.769539938144905\\
    0.68    0.80013652111508\\
    0.72    0.829966157039111\\
    0.76    0.857651154565616\\
    0.8 0.88476878274115\\
    0.84    0.909807963488884\\
    0.88    0.934472859382262\\
    0.92    0.957106584454481\\
    0.96    0.979554468759097\\
    1   1\\
    };
    \end{axis}

    \begin{axis}[%
    width=8.333in,
    height=6.25in,
    at={(0in,6.25in)},
    scale only axis,
    clip=false,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=1,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1,
    axis line style={draw=none},
    ticks=none,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    axis y line*=left
    ]
    \node[align=center]
    at (axis cs:0.5,-0.05) {\boldmath$(\dot{m}Cp)_{ch} > (\dot{m}Cp)_{fr}$};
    \end{axis}

    \begin{axis}[%
    width=2.789in,
    height=2.002in,
    at={(4.753in,0.667in)},
    scale only axis,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=1,
    xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
    xlabel={Longueur adimensionnelle [-]},
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1,
    ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
    ylabel={Température adimensionnelle [-]},
    axis background/.style={fill=white},
    xmajorgrids,
    ymajorgrids
    ]
    \addplot [color=blue, line width=2.0pt, forget plot]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    0   0\\
    0.04    0.0676274275735169\\
    0.08    0.132237336302444\\
    0.12    0.193527538434779\\
    0.16    0.252130726267156\\
    0.2 0.307672285856181\\
    0.24    0.36083209428148\\
    0.28    0.41115844195306\\
    0.32    0.459385938267647\\
    0.36    0.504980422349553\\
    0.4 0.548739307522211\\
    0.44    0.590039835766951\\
    0.48    0.629750897407565\\
    0.52    0.667154142344658\\
    0.56    0.703199295563746\\
    0.6 0.737064503866606\\
    0.64    0.769790458830425\\
    0.68    0.800442901280363\\
    0.72    0.830164492681368\\
    0.76    0.857898587859836\\
    0.8 0.884901798275498\\
    0.84    0.90998393998255\\
    0.88    0.93452864615589\\
    0.92    0.957199761707603\\
    0.96    0.979522230176349\\
    1   1\\
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
```

Comment: Take a look at the subcaption package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To adjust your plots to half of the textwidth I use the `adjustbox` environment. For the aligment and the captions of the subfigures I used the `subcaption` package. You can refer to them using the subfigures labels (e.g. `\label{fig:sub1}`). For centering everything and the overall caption I used a normal `figure`-environment with an additional `\centering` command.

Your example didn't compile for me at first, so I had to comment some lines out. Especially the `\node`s inside the `axis`-enviromnents. Furthermore I commented out `height=6.25in, at={(0in,6.25in)}` in some of the `axis`-environments, which seems to be an (unwanted) artifact of the conversion using `matlab2tikz`.

Here is the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz, amsmath, pgfplots, adjustbox, subcaption, here}


\begin{document}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% First Tikz %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.49\textwidth}
    \begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[%
        width=6.458in,
        height=2.002in,
        at={(1.083in,3.476in)},
        scale only axis,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=15,
        xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
        xlabel={Longueur [m]},
        ymin=20,
        ymax=60,
        ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
        ylabel={$\text{Température [}^\circ\text{C]}$},
        axis background/.style={fill=white},
        xmajorgrids,
        ymajorgrids,
        legend style={at={(0.731,0.921)}, anchor=south west, legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=white!15!black}
        ]
        \addplot [color=red, line width=2.0pt]
          table[row sep=crcr]{%
        0   60\\
        0.6 58.2422860842627\\
        1.2 56.6097827135196\\
        1.8 55.1008390654262\\
        2.4 53.6983457588748\\
        3   52.4031055642289\\
        3.6 51.1980468733326\\
        4.2 50.0864145734772\\
        4.8 49.0508026074216\\
        5.4 48.0969489200673\\
        6   47.2067330247575\\
        6.6 46.3884947789133\\
        7.2 45.623002700944\\
        7.8 44.9213678568538\\
        8.4 44.2628254074828\\
        9   43.6614912955672\\
        9.6 43.0946093537078\\
        10.2    42.5796038678164\\
        10.8    42.0912231257453\\
        11.4    41.6505800688117\\
        12  41.2293652659884\\
        12.6    40.8528463044577\\
        13.2    40.4890228447549\\
        13.8    40.1678796111365\\
        14.4    39.8530064435973\\
        15  39.5797772593885\\
        };
        \addlegendentry{Fluide chaud};

        \addplot [color=blue, line width=2.0pt]
          table[row sep=crcr]{%
        0   20\\
        0.6 21.1719747209521\\
        1.2 22.2595912274186\\
        1.8 23.2656950493128\\
        2.4 24.1999453099989\\
        3   25.0635558718899\\
        3.6 25.8661605546952\\
        4.2 26.6073449950241\\
        4.8 27.2969658727417\\
        5.4 27.9329466611327\\
        6   28.5256202326883\\
        6.6 29.071175348496\\
        7.2 29.5806854597249\\
        7.8 30.0484917709108\\
        8.4 30.4866898930294\\
        9   30.8876177140669\\
        9.6 31.2646983217632\\
        10.2    31.6080639948758\\
        10.8    31.9328014426398\\
        11.4    32.2265838113194\\
        12  32.5065362120139\\
        12.6    32.7575620167737\\
        13.2    32.9992468597154\\
        13.8    33.2133493639172\\
        14.4    33.4223949531101\\
        15  33.6045493133708\\
        };
        \addlegendentry{Fluide Froid}
        \end{axis}

        \begin{axis}[%
        width=2.789in,
        height=2.002in,
        at={(1.083in,0.667in)},
        scale only axis,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=1,
        xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
        xlabel={Longueur adimensionnelle [-]},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=1,
        ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
        ylabel={Température adimensionnelle [-]},
        axis background/.style={fill=white},
        xmajorgrids,
        ymajorgrids
        ]
        \addplot [color=red, line width=2.0pt, forget plot]
          table[row sep=crcr]{%
        0   -0\\
        0.04    0.0860771176722571\\
        0.08    0.166022541945048\\
        0.12    0.239917115342254\\
        0.16    0.308598702432005\\
        0.2 0.372027990696816\\
        0.24    0.431040994923242\\
        0.28    0.485478809533588\\
        0.32    0.536193827641397\\
        0.36    0.582905055989428\\
        0.4 0.626499874058642\\
        0.44    0.666569870171705\\
        0.48    0.704056830411705\\
        0.52    0.738416634073142\\
        0.56    0.770666157388152\\
        0.6 0.800114127645579\\
        0.64    0.82787493853683\\
        0.68    0.853095304271001\\
        0.72    0.877011828016837\\
        0.76    0.898590586609769\\
        0.8 0.919217922960301\\
        0.84    0.937656456482359\\
        0.88    0.955473277793484\\
        0.92    0.971200003094069\\
        0.96    0.986619676598071\\
        1   1\\
        };
        \end{axis}

        \begin{axis}[%
        width=8.333in,
        % height=6.25in,
        % at={(0in,6.25in)},
        scale only axis,
        clip=false,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=1,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=1,
        axis line style={draw=none},
        ticks=none,
        axis x line*=bottom,
        axis y line*=left
        ]
        % \node[align=center]
        % at (axis cs:0.5,-0.05) {\boldmath$(\dot{m}Cp)_{ch} < (\dot{m}Cp)_{fr}$};
        \end{axis}

        \begin{axis}[%
        width=2.789in,
        height=2.002in,
        at={(4.753in,0.667in)},
        scale only axis,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=1,
        xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
        xlabel={Longueur adimensionnelle [-]},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=1,
        ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
        ylabel={Température adimensionnelle [-]},
        axis background/.style={fill=white},
        xmajorgrids,
        ymajorgrids
        ]
        \addplot [color=blue, line width=2.0pt, forget plot]
          table[row sep=crcr]{%
        0   0\\
        0.04    0.0861457953480524\\
        0.08    0.166090855005231\\
        0.12    0.240044339146409\\
        0.16    0.308716239932408\\
        0.2 0.372195782106014\\
        0.24    0.431191097887369\\
        0.28    0.485671729568455\\
        0.32    0.536362190665889\\
        0.36    0.583109846449379\\
        0.4 0.626674212890625\\
        0.44    0.666775145544934\\
        0.48    0.70422659648922\\
        0.52    0.738612616960049\\
        0.56    0.770822292710784\\
        0.6 0.800292421548015\\
        0.64    0.828009665170759\\
        0.68    0.853248698467887\\
        0.72    0.877118467343273\\
        0.76    0.898712888585209\\
        0.8 0.919290740467402\\
        0.84    0.937742348012608\\
        0.88    0.955507349805372\\
        0.92    0.971244916649378\\
        0.96    0.986610775846745\\
        1   1\\
        };
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}% 
    \end{adjustbox}     
    \caption{subfigure 1}
    \label{fig:sub1}
    \end{subfigure}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Second Tikz  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{subfigure}{.49\textwidth}
    \begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
    width=6.458in,
    height=2.002in,
    at={(1.083in,3.476in)},
    scale only axis,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=15,
    xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
    xlabel={Longueur [m]},
    ymin=20,
    ymax=60,
    ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
    ylabel={$\text{Température [}^\circ\text{C]}$},
    axis background/.style={fill=white},
    xmajorgrids,
    ymajorgrids,
    legend style={at={(0.731,0.921)}, anchor=south west, legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=white!15!black}
    ]
    \addplot [color=red, line width=2.0pt]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    0   60\\
    0.6 58.7776348332645\\
    1.2 57.6257077366681\\
    1.8 56.5488849048322\\
    2.4 55.533142320904\\
    3   54.5846308646345\\
    3.6 53.6888444560077\\
    4.2 52.8534727394519\\
    4.8 52.0633330247601\\
    5.4 51.3277392203579\\
    6   50.6306266766885\\
    6.6 49.9830450249816\\
    7.2 49.367828223399\\
    7.8 48.797900823873\\
    8.4 48.2547583690078\\
    9   47.753369491308\\
    9.6 47.2736329167244\\
    10.2    46.8327631818274\\
    10.8    46.4087782880983\\
    11.4    46.0213763868627\\
    12  45.6463808042967\\
    12.6    45.3062507013489\\
    13.2    44.9742657188535\\
    13.8    44.6759675374661\\
    14.4    44.381702467235\\
    15  44.1204654697768\\
    };
    \addlegendentry{Fluide chaud}

    \addplot [color=blue, line width=2.0pt]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    0   20\\
    0.6 21.2228559170426\\
    1.2 22.3729085239176\\
    1.8 23.4501552374234\\
    2.4 24.4639532309607\\
    3   25.4128227501518\\
    3.6 26.3066027900671\\
    4.2 27.1422745774569\\
    4.8 27.930353477233\\
    5.4 28.6661962597015\\
    6   29.3612000017676\\
    6.6 30.008985621116\\
    7.2 30.6220513246524\\
    7.8 31.1921430440547\\
    8.4 31.7330971164275\\
    9   32.2346153949974\\
    9.6 32.7121307165636\\
    10.2    33.1530991038253\\
    10.8    33.5748337604652\\
    11.4    33.9623072445142\\
    12  34.3350270270729\\
    12.6    34.6752048895403\\
    13.2    35.0048915196913\\
    13.8    35.3032165027917\\
    14.4    35.5951633170568\\
    15  35.85640755331\\
    };
    \addlegendentry{Fluide Froid}

    \end{axis}

    \begin{axis}[%
    width=2.789in,
    height=2.002in,
    at={(1.083in,0.667in)},
    scale only axis,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=1,
    xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
    xlabel={Longueur adimensionnelle [-]},
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1,
    ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
    ylabel={Température adimensionnelle [-]},
    axis background/.style={fill=white},
    xmajorgrids,
    ymajorgrids
    ]
    \addplot [color=red, line width=2.0pt, forget plot]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    0   -0\\
    0.04    0.0769773927824497\\
    0.08    0.149519008810551\\
    0.12    0.21733099849995\\
    0.16    0.281296512224227\\
    0.2 0.341028203632703\\
    0.24    0.397439580611159\\
    0.28    0.450046394429651\\
    0.32    0.499804761917564\\
    0.36    0.546128147719719\\
    0.4 0.590028209295366\\
    0.44    0.630809105641815\\
    0.48    0.669551853447909\\
    0.52    0.705442540195765\\
    0.56    0.739646468140343\\
    0.6 0.771221000551574\\
    0.64    0.801431997836821\\
    0.68    0.82919538939329\\
    0.72    0.855895472630752\\
    0.76    0.8802917734479\\
    0.8 0.903906797040198\\
    0.84    0.925326197105136\\
    0.88    0.946232665230102\\
    0.92    0.965017736090942\\
    0.96    0.983548825252973\\
    1   1\\
    };
    \end{axis}

    \begin{axis}[%
    width=8.333in,
    % height=6.25in,
    % at={(0in,6.25in)},
    scale only axis,
    clip=false,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=1,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1,
    axis line style={draw=none},
    ticks=none,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    axis y line*=left
    ]
    % \node[align=center]
    % at (axis cs:0.5,-0.05) {\boldmath$(\dot{m}Cp)_{ch} \simeq (\dot{m}Cp)_{fr}$};
    \end{axis}

    \begin{axis}[%
    width=2.789in,
    height=2.002in,
    at={(4.753in,0.667in)},
    scale only axis,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=1,
    xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
    xlabel={Longueur adimensionnelle [-]},
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1,
    ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
    ylabel={Température adimensionnelle [-]},
    axis background/.style={fill=white},
    xmajorgrids,
    ymajorgrids
    ]
    \addplot [color=blue, line width=2.0pt, forget plot]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    0   0\\
    0.04    0.0771206159359437\\
    0.08    0.149649819225429\\
    0.12    0.217587446956305\\
    0.16    0.281523618508965\\
    0.2 0.341365011712371\\
    0.24    0.397732132506308\\
    0.28    0.450434598974842\\
    0.32    0.500135572989705\\
    0.36    0.546542224685216\\
    0.4 0.590373321970617\\
    0.44    0.63122656172057\\
    0.48    0.66989015569514\\
    0.52    0.705843552924974\\
    0.56    0.739959355672478\\
    0.6 0.771588101142333\\
    0.64    0.801703076426661\\
    0.68    0.829513183210251\\
    0.72    0.85611029577954\\
    0.76    0.88054669366767\\
    0.8 0.904052634802546\\
    0.84    0.925506287612849\\
    0.88    0.946298300497392\\
    0.92    0.965112460142155\\
    0.96    0.983524374271102\\
    1   1\\
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}% 
    \end{adjustbox}
  \caption{subfigure 2}
  \label{fig:sub2}
    \end{subfigure}    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Third Tikz %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{subfigure}{.49\textwidth}
    \begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
    width=6.458in,
    height=2.002in,
    at={(1.083in,3.476in)},
    scale only axis,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=15,
    xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
    xlabel={Longueur [m]},
    ymin=20,
    ymax=60,
    ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
    ylabel={$\text{Température [}^\circ\text{C]}$},
    axis background/.style={fill=white},
    xmajorgrids,
    ymajorgrids,
    legend style={at={(0.731,0.921)}, anchor=south west, legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=white!15!black}
    ]
    \addplot [color=red, line width=2.0pt]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    0   60\\
    0.6 59.3647493077178\\
    1.2 58.7563210104658\\
    1.8 58.1805874622794\\
    2.4 57.6285690083078\\
    3   57.1068219696446\\
    3.6 56.605922919731\\
    4.2 56.1331528874796\\
    4.8 55.6785737145958\\
    5.4 55.2502415177202\\
    6   54.837627516618\\
    6.6 54.4496207252873\\
    7.2 54.075020193811\\
    7.8 53.7236136265699\\
    8.4 53.383439917122\\
    9   53.0652598668396\\
    9.6 52.7562569435763\\
    10.2    52.4682487786268\\
    10.8    52.1874599496269\\
    11.4    51.9268587791624\\
    12  51.6715983033036\\
    12.6    51.4359024249101\\
    13.2    51.2037297207932\\
    13.8    50.9906765955349\\
    14.4    50.7793728047856\\
    15  50.5869173289617\\
    };
    \addlegendentry{Fluide chaud}

    \addplot [color=blue, line width=2.0pt]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    0   20\\
    0.6 21.2712089630829\\
    1.2 22.4856969012925\\
    1.8 23.6377835190348\\
    2.4 24.7393616850351\\
    3   25.7833896912226\\
    3.6 26.7826473499964\\
    4.2 27.7286437679408\\
    4.8 28.6351875739359\\
    5.4 29.4922380179891\\
    6   30.314784269442\\
    6.6 31.091120196573\\
    7.2 31.8375785390289\\
    7.8 32.5406562978381\\
    8.4 33.2182056811558\\
    9   33.8547781174572\\
    9.6 34.4699357357213\\
    10.2    35.0461170423426\\
    10.8    35.6048009187176\\
    11.4    36.1261253522921\\
    12  36.6337111698228\\
    12.6    37.1051861984516\\
    13.2    37.5665589225563\\
    13.8    37.9927133147384\\
    14.4    38.4123141041482\\
    15  38.7972396510423\\
    };
    \addlegendentry{Fluide Froid}

    \end{axis}

    \begin{axis}[%
    width=2.789in,
    height=2.002in,
    at={(1.083in,0.667in)},
    scale only axis,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=1,
    xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
    xlabel={Longueur adimensionnelle [-]},
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1,
    ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
    ylabel={Température adimensionnelle [-]},
    axis background/.style={fill=white},
    xmajorgrids,
    ymajorgrids
    ]
    \addplot [color=red, line width=2.0pt, forget plot]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    0   -0\\
    0.04    0.0674859357431074\\
    0.08    0.132122391037815\\
    0.12    0.193285515627999\\
    0.16    0.251929264255641\\
    0.2 0.307357125339714\\
    0.24    0.360570197764412\\
    0.28    0.410794980524046\\
    0.32    0.459087255092337\\
    0.36    0.504591178923097\\
    0.4 0.548425278284803\\
    0.44    0.589645227677622\\
    0.48    0.629440961399251\\
    0.52    0.666772681466085\\
    0.56    0.702911077498078\\
    0.6 0.736712974432583\\
    0.64    0.769539938144905\\
    0.68    0.80013652111508\\
    0.72    0.829966157039111\\
    0.76    0.857651154565616\\
    0.8 0.88476878274115\\
    0.84    0.909807963488884\\
    0.88    0.934472859382262\\
    0.92    0.957106584454481\\
    0.96    0.979554468759097\\
    1   1\\
    };
    \end{axis}

    \begin{axis}[%
    width=8.333in,
    % height=6.25in,
    % at={(0in,6.25in)},
    scale only axis,
    clip=false,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=1,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1,
    axis line style={draw=none},
    ticks=none,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    axis y line*=left
    ]
    % \node[align=center]
    % at (axis cs:0.5,-0.05) {\boldmath$(\dot{m}Cp)_{ch} > (\dot{m}Cp)_{fr}$};
    \end{axis}

    \begin{axis}[%
    width=2.789in,
    height=2.002in,
    at={(4.753in,0.667in)},
    scale only axis,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=1,
    xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
    xlabel={Longueur adimensionnelle [-]},
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1,
    ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
    ylabel={Température adimensionnelle [-]},
    axis background/.style={fill=white},
    xmajorgrids,
    ymajorgrids
    ]
    \addplot [color=blue, line width=2.0pt, forget plot]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    0   0\\
    0.04    0.0676274275735169\\
    0.08    0.132237336302444\\
    0.12    0.193527538434779\\
    0.16    0.252130726267156\\
    0.2 0.307672285856181\\
    0.24    0.36083209428148\\
    0.28    0.41115844195306\\
    0.32    0.459385938267647\\
    0.36    0.504980422349553\\
    0.4 0.548739307522211\\
    0.44    0.590039835766951\\
    0.48    0.629750897407565\\
    0.52    0.667154142344658\\
    0.56    0.703199295563746\\
    0.6 0.737064503866606\\
    0.64    0.769790458830425\\
    0.68    0.800442901280363\\
    0.72    0.830164492681368\\
    0.76    0.857898587859836\\
    0.8 0.884901798275498\\
    0.84    0.90998393998255\\
    0.88    0.93452864615589\\
    0.92    0.957199761707603\\
    0.96    0.979522230176349\\
    1   1\\
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}% 
    \end{adjustbox}
    \caption{subfigure 3}
    \label{fig:sub3}
    \end{subfigure}
  \caption{All figures caption}
  \label{fig:plots}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And the result

[image]